# EA create multiple instances of Custom Indicators

Tags: mql4

When I use the Custom Indicator, it shows the graph as follows:

[image]
When I use the Expert Advisor with the Custom Indicator, it shows the following:

[image]
It also repeated opened a lot of custom indicator when I am doing backtesting.

How should I change the EA such that

1. It only opened a Custom Indicator;
2. It plots the same graph as the Custom Indicator

Below is the code for a Custom Indicator ( **`HitBollingerBand1.mq4`** )

```
#property indicator_chart_window 
#property indicator_buffers 2 

sinput string s_  = " Bolinger Bands ";   //  ind#1
input int      InpBandsPeriod    = 20;    //period
input double   InpBandsDeviation = 2.0;   //deviation

double CrossedUp[];
double CrossedDown[];

int limit, x;
double POINT;

int init()
  {

   SetIndexStyle(0, DRAW_ARROW, 1, 2,clrRed);
   SetIndexBuffer(0,CrossedUp);
   SetIndexStyle(1, DRAW_ARROW, 1, 2,clrRed);
   SetIndexBuffer(1,CrossedDown);
   POINT=0.0001;
   return(0);
  }

int start()
  {

   int counted_bars=IndicatorCounted();
   if(counted_bars<0) return(-1); 
   if(counted_bars>0) counted_bars--;
   limit=Bars-counted_bars; 


   for(int i=limit; i>=0; i--) { 
      isHitBollingerBand(i);     
   }
   return(0);
  }


void isHitBollingerBand(int candleIdx){        
        int dir[]={1,-1};
         bool setUp=false;
         bool setDown=false;
        for (int j=0;j<ArraySize(dir);j++){
            double bands = iBands(_Symbol,0,InpBandsPeriod,InpBandsDeviation,0,PRICE_CLOSE,dir[j]<0?MODE_LOWER:MODE_UPPER,candleIdx);
            double _peak = dir[j]<0 ? iLow(_Symbol,0,candleIdx): iHigh(_Symbol,0,candleIdx);  
            if(dir[j] * (_peak-NormalizeDouble(bands,Digits) ) >= 0){                         
              double result=_peak+ dir[j]*3*POINT;
              if(dir[j]==1)
               CrossedUp[candleIdx]=result;
              else
               CrossedDown[candleIdx]=result;                  
      }            
    }

}
```

Below is the code of EA makes use of the Custom Indicator ( `HitBollingerBandEA.mq4` )

```
int init()
  {     
   start();
   return(0);
  }
sinput string s_  = " Bolinger Bands ";   //  ind#1
input int      InpBandsPeriod    = 20;    //period
input double   InpBandsDeviation = 2.0;   //deviation
int start()
  {
         double HitBollingerBandUp=iCustom(NULL, 0, "HitBollingerBand1", InpBandsPeriod,InpBandsDeviation,0,1);
         double HitBollingerBandDown=iCustom(NULL, 0, "HitBollingerBand1", InpBandsPeriod,InpBandsDeviation,1,1);
         if(HitBollingerBandUp!=EMPTY_VALUE){
            printf("%i%s [%s]",__LINE__,__FUNCTION__,TimeToStr(Time[1],TIME_DATE|TIME_MINUTES));                 
        }
   return(0);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

### EA type of MQL4-code
does not influence,
what all **`CustomIndicator`**-s type of `MQL4`-code get painted on GUI

---

This said, one can "read" from EA-side any value from any CustomIndicator-buffers using **`iCustom()`**. But that does not mean, there are any lines painted on GUI Window.

---

### If one plans
to see all the lines
programmed inside a **`CustomIndicator`**-type of `MQL4`-code

then one has to "place" the **`CustomIndicator`** "onto" GUI Window. Either manually, or programmatically ( using the launch-time "profile" definition ).

---

**Q2:** How should I change the EA such that it plots the same graph as the **`Custom Indicator`**?

**A2:** In a case of such a need, we trans-code the whole `CustomIndicator` logic into EA, so that the EA does all the GUI operations under it's own control, not relying on manual GUI setup of a Graph.

Comment: Thanks, how do I make sure that it only opens an instance of indicator rather than opened huge amount instances of indicators after each call of start() in EA? I just need to get the returned value of custom indicator without rewriting the code to EA

Comment: Opening an EA does not "open" anything visually perceivable. Just the internal mechanics of the automated CustomIndicator buffer management & OnCalculate() batch-driven block-updates + further live, ad-hoc updates of hot-end ( reverse-indexed as always [0] ) starts under a common ( shared ... ( !!! ) ) thread responsible for internal updates. Nothing goes to screen from just calling an iCustom(...) method to fetch a one-cell value from some of the (referred) CustomIndicator buffers. **So if you are happy with just many values, get 'em via iCustom() into EA and nothing gets painted on Graph.**